# Best way to preserve gall stones outside of body

Tags: gallbladder, gallstone

I’ve got a few gall stones in a jar and I’d like to keep them on display so people can see what they look like.

Is there an appropriate solution for keeping them in?

I imagine if they were floating around in something it’d be possible for people to get a look from all the angles.

Will leaving them in an empty jar (just air) cause them to break down over time?

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences. Your question would be better suited to Biology.SE, but it lacks prior research, which both this site and Biology require so we can't migrate it. Have you attempted to find the answer on your own? You need to at least try and [edit] your question to show us what you found and why it doesn't answer your question.